# How to solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{e^x}\,dx$ step by step?

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponentiation

I'm primitive in integrals and derivatives and I'm trying to solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{e^x}\,dx$, but especially this integral was hard to me to solve it.

So I tried:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{e^x}\,dx&=\int \frac{1}{\color{Red}{e^x}}\color{Blue}{e^x\,dx}\\&=\int \frac{1}{\color{Red}{u}}\,\color{Blue}{du}\\&=\ln\left(|u|\right)\\&=\ln \left(|e^x|\right)+C
\end{align}$$

But my solution is wrong while I used the integration by substitution method ?!

---

**Correct answer:**

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{e^x}\,dx&=\left(-e^{-x}\right)+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your very first equation is wrong. Look at it again!

Comment: The substitution you made puts an $e^x$ where there was none to start. You can't just put $e^x$ in from nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int dx\frac{1}{e^x} = \int e^{-x}dx =$$
With substitution $y=-x$:
$$=-\int e^ydy = -e^y +C = -e^{-x} +C$$

---

Your solution is wrong because the first step is wrong:
$$\int dx\frac{1}{e^x}\neq \int dx\frac{1}{e^x}e^x$$
If you apply the substitution $u=e^x$ correctly you get:
$$\int dx\frac{1}{e^x} = \int\frac{1}{u^2}du = -u^{-1}+C = -e^{-x}+C$$

Comment: The OP is asking why is his solution wrong

Comment: @Shobhit: Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can use the substitution method for integrating $$\int \frac 1{e^x} \,dx = \int e^{-x} \, dx $$

$$\text{Put}\;\;\color{blue}{\bf u = -x} \implies du = -\,dx \iff  \color{red}{\bf -\,du = dx}$$

Substituting then gives us $$\begin{align} \int e^{\color{blue}{\bf -x}} \,\color{red}{\bf dx}  & = \int e^\color{blue}{\bf u} (\color{red}{\bf -\,du}) \\& = -\int e^u\,du \\ \\ & = -e^u + C \\  & = - e^{-x} + C \\ \\ & = \frac{-1}{e^x} + C\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you that was more clarification

Comment: You're welcome Mohammad. Sorry I couldn't have been of more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the steps, one by one, or all steps at once by inserting the following codes in Maple:

```
  [> with(Student[Calculus1]):
     IntTutor(1/exp(x), x);
```

[image]